# create fn function with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, callback

I did the following little plugIn (to add to query.transit by Rico St Cruz):

```
$.fn.translateLeft = function( left, duration, easing, callback ) {
  var $this  = $(this);
  var currentLeftPx = parseInt( $this.css('left') );
  var parentWidth = $this.parent().width();
  // final left layout destination in px
  var finalLeftPx = parentWidth/100 * left; 
  // actual distances to final left layout destination in px
  var distanceLeftPx = currentLeftPx - finalLeftPx;

  $this.transition( { x: -distanceLeftPx }, duration, easing, function() {
      $this.stop(true).css( { left: left +'%', x: 0 } );
      callback();
  } ); 
}
```

I used it (without the callback I tried to implement it worked well so far) so:

```
$("#someElement").translateLeft( 10.5, 300, 'easeOutSine', function() { 
                // do something else
            } );
```

This helps to make smooth x translate instead of left, yet keeps the possibility to set % values that refer to the parent (which is not possible with x alone which refers alway to the element). This only for explanation.

And as I said it works very good, yet my inserted callback does not.
Did I do something wrong here semantically?

Thanks for advice!
Garavani

EDIT:

Thanks so far for your comments that made me think. Actually even in my (beginner) fn code the callback actually works if I put for example alert( "Callback" ) in there instead of the other code. So it seems it is not possible to mix up my plugIn with any kind of code. To complete my question here is the whole code involved even if I am quite aware that it is quite complicated and will make you run out of nerves.:

This is the function IN which I liked to use my plugIn:

```
function switchMenuItem( id ) {

var $menuItem = $("#"+ id );

var $menu = $menuItem.parent();
var $menuImg = $menu.children(); //all siblings including selected element by id
var $prev = $menuItem.prev();
// calculate animation values
var index = $menuImg.index( $menuItem );    
var ww = $(window).width();
var cssLeftPx = parseInt( $menuItem.css('left') );      
var cssLeftPercent = 100 * cssLeftPx/ww;        

if ( index == 1 ) { var dur = ww/2.4; };        
if ( index == 2 ) { var dur = ww/1.5; };
$menuItem   .stop(true)
            .animate( { left: '10.5%' }, dur, 'easeOutSine', function() { 
                $(this)  .prependTo($menu );
            } );
$menuImg    .first()
            .stop(true)
            .animate( { left: cssLeftPercent+'%' }, dur, 'easeOutSine', function() { 
                $(this)  .insertAfter( $prev ); 
                $menuItem.siblings()
                         .animate( { opacity: 1 }, 150, 'linear' )
                         .css( { cursor: 'pointer' } );                 
                switchComplete = true;
                subReady = true;            
            } );
…

}
```

and I would love to get rid of the query animate and substitute it with a smooth x translate with the help of Rico St Cruz transit plugIn (in the way I did successfully before with my kind of plugIn:

```
$.fn.translateLeft = function( left, duration, easing, callback ) {

var $this  = $(this);
var currentLeftPx = parseInt( $this.css('left') );
var parentWidth = $this.parent().width();
// final left layout destination in px
var finalLeftPx = parentWidth/100 * left; 
// actual distances to final left layout destination in px
var distanceLeftPx = currentLeftPx - finalLeftPx;

$this.transition( { x: -distanceLeftPx }, duration, easing, function() {
    $this.stop(true).css( { left: left +'%', x: 0 } );
    callback();
} );
```

}

So instead of „animate“ I want to use „translate Left“ which uses a smooth x translate and then return at the end a „cleaned up“ css position so that it is ready for other window resizing etc.

Did I explain myself? Any advice is appreciated a lot. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You normally return something inside plugin code

Comment: How do you know your callback is not working? What code does it contain?

Comment: In this case the code was something like:$("#anotherElement").transition( { opacity: 1 }, 150, 'linear' ); so I saw it didn’t work. It would be so great if you could write me how a professionell plugIn would look. Tried to google but didn’t understand, thanks! Oops, there was also something with $(this)  .insertAfter( element ); Did „this“ create the problem?